# AJAX Edits -- "Dirty" flag not being cleared on cancel

Tags: support, status-completed, edits, answers, inline-editor

I must say I like the new AJAX-esque edit on SO however there seems to be a small bug (or what I would consider a bug).

If you edit your post it now shows up in-line allowing you to modify the entry. This also appears to set a "dirty" flag (as it's done in the past) which is used to alert the user when leaving the page that they have pending edits. I notice, however, that if you edit a post and cancel out of it, this dirty flag is not reset. e.g.

1. You open a question
2. You click "Edit" on your post and proceed editing

   - dirty flag is set
3. You hit cancel (with your changes you *were going* to apply)

   - A warning box is presented asking if you would like to abandon changes (you click yes)
4. You're now back to the page as if you didn't edit at all
5. You go to leave the page and, despite canceling, you're still warned of leaving a page with pending modifications.

Is this the intended behavior? I feel like a cancel should exempt the warning box when leaving the page, no?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yeah, you're absolutely right, that doesn't make any sense and was a plain oversight.

Fixed in the next build.

Comment: Awesome, glad to know it wasn't just me.